# Merge columns from one dataframe to another (left_join doesn't work) - rstudio

Tags: r, merge, left-join

I have two dataframes:

**df1**: My main dataset with an address column

**df2**: A database containing latitudes and longitudes plus and address column

I want to merge two columns over from df2 to my df1.

**df1**:

```
ID    VAR1   VAR2   VARX      Address
 1     7      2       x     Road 1, 1234 City
 2     8      0       y     Road 4, 1234 City
 3     6      2       x     Road 5, 1234 City
 4     7      2       x     Road 6, 1234 City
 5     4      1       y     Road 10, 1234 City
 6     1      2       x     Road 11, 1234 City
```

**df2**:

```
    Address            Latitude      Longitude
Road 1, 1234 City        12,67          56,78
Road 2, 1234 City        12,66          55,67
Road 3, 1234 City        12,45          55,10
Road 4, 1234 City        12,10          55,20
Road 5, 1234 City        11,50          55,30
Road 6, 1234 City        12,34          55,32
Road 7, 1234 City        12,89          55,40
Road 8, 1234 City        12,77          55,45
Road 9, 1234 City        11,67          55,67
Road 10, 1234 City       11,90          55,78
Road 11, 1234 City       11,12          56,59
```

So my new dataframe would look like this:

**new dataframe, df3**:

```
ID    VAR1   VAR2   VARX      Address            Latitude   Longitude
 1     7      2       x     Road 1, 1234 City     12,67       56,78
 2     8      0       y     Road 4, 1234 City     12,10       55,20
 3     6      2       x     Road 5, 1234 City     11,50       55,30
 4     7      2       x     Road 6, 1234 City     12,34       55,32
 5     4      1       y     Road 10, 1234 City    11,90       55,78
 6     1      2       x     Road 11, 1234 City    11,12       56,59
```

I've tried a **left_join**, but it only returns NA.

```
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("Address"))
```

**EDIT: SOLVED**
Apprently I had some wrong spaces in one of my address columns. The code above does work.

Comment: More information if needed:

- df1 contains rows on the address column that won't match those in df2
- df2 contains a lot of rows on the address column that won't match those in df1

What I want is really how to do the Excel Vlookup.

Comment: could you mabe supply your data using `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)`?

Comment: I still get the same

Answer (score 1):

`left_join` should work fine. 
Have a look to this and check your data structure.

```
df3 <- dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = "Address")
```

**Output**

```
  ID VAR1 VAR2 VARX            Address Latitude Longitude
1  1    7    2    x  Road 1, 1234 City    12,67     56,78
2  2    8    0    y  Road 4, 1234 City    12,10     55,20
3  3    6    2    x  Road 5, 1234 City    11,50     55,30
4  4    7    2    x  Road 6, 1234 City    12,34     55,32
5  5    4    1    y Road 10, 1234 City    11,90     55,78
6  6    1    2    x Road 11, 1234 City    11,12     56,59
```

**Data**

*df1*

```
structure(list(ID = 1:6, VAR1 = c(7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 1L), VAR2 = c(2L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), VARX = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("x", "y"), class = "factor"), Address = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Road 1, 1234 City", "Road 10, 1234 City", 
"Road 11, 1234 City", "Road 4, 1234 City", "Road 5, 1234 City", 
"Road 6, 1234 City"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "VAR1", 
"VAR2", "VARX", "Address"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

*df2*

```
structure(list(Address = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Road 1, 1234 City", "Road 10, 1234 City", 
"Road 11, 1234 City", "Road 2, 1234 City", "Road 3, 1234 City", 
"Road 4, 1234 City", "Road 5, 1234 City", "Road 6, 1234 City", 
"Road 7, 1234 City", "Road 8, 1234 City", "Road 9, 1234 City"
), class = "factor"), Latitude = structure(c(9L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 
2L, 6L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("11,12", "11,50", "11,67", 
"11,90", "12,10", "12,34", "12,45", "12,66", "12,67", "12,77", 
"12,89"), class = "factor"), Longitude = structure(c(10L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("55,10", "55,20", 
"55,30", "55,32", "55,40", "55,45", "55,67", "55,78", "56,59", 
"56,78"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Address", "Latitude", 
"Longitude"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this however I only get blank columns. I thought maybe it's because there were some kind of difference between the address variable ind both dataframes, but it's possible to search an address out, so I guess they're the same. 

Does it make a difference that my df1 has addresses that won't match my df2 and my df2 has addresses that won't match df1?

Answer (score 1):

Base R Function

```
merge(df1,df2,by = "Address")
```

output

```
      Address        ID  VAR1 VAR2 VARX Latitude Longitude
1  Road 1, 1234 City  1    7    2    x    12,67     56,78
2 Road 10, 1234 City  5    4    1    y    11,90     55,78
3 Road 11, 1234 City  6    1    2    x    11,12     56,59
4  Road 4, 1234 City  2    8    0    y    12,10     55,20
5  Road 5, 1234 City  3    6    2    x    11,50     55,30
6  Road 6, 1234 City  4    7    2    x    12,34     55,32
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've found the mistake - and I feel kinda stupid now. In the making of my address variable I accidentially put in a space before the comma.